# Difficulty Declaring Structure

Tags: visual-c++, data-structures, scanf, declare

I am quite a noob currently. So I have been learning about structures specifically defining and declaring them. So in this sample the issue I am getting is in the line:

```
 scanf("%d", &mybox.topleft.x);
```

"mybox" is underlined in red and I have an error there. I do not understand why! I have declared mybox as a variable of the type type_RECTANGLE. Here is some of  the code:

```
typedef struct type_COORD
{
int x, y;
};

typedef struct type_RECTANGLE
{
int topleft;
int bottomrt;
};

int main()
{
int length, width, area;
char ch;
type_RECTANGLE mybox;

//input coordinates
printf("Enter top left x coordinate...");
scanf("%d", &mybox.topleft.x);
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {}
```

Any help is much appreciated, I am sure I'm making a very simple nooby mistake!

Dean

Answer (score 0):

Here if you see below code

```
scanf("%d", &mybox.topleft.x);
```

topleft is member variable of type_RECTANGLE, so you can use mybox.topleft. But you are using topleft.x , and here topleft is an int variable and x is not any member of this. So you can not take input this way.
If you want to take input for topleft try this :

```
scanf("%d", &mybox.topleft);
```

Comment: I am required to keep the line 
    scanf("%d", &mybox.topleft.x);

so is there any way I could declare type_RECTANGLE differently to make this work?

Comment: then you should declare topleft as type_COORD.